# PHP exec() not executing batch files

Tags: php, windows, exec, less

I tried googling for this issue and found many people with the same problem but no solution.

```
    $result = exec("C:\\Ruby191\\bin\\lessc.bat less\\$file", $output);
```

Here `result` is an empty string and `output` an empty array. Same thing with:

```
    $result = exec("cmd /c C:\\Ruby191\\bin\\lessc.bat less\\$file", $output);
```

I am sure the path is correct; I am sure exec() is enabled.

I tried `exec`, `shell_exec`, `system` and none work.

lessc is [less CSS](http://lesscss.org/).

---

**EDIT**

The apache error log says:

> '"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: Did you try forward slashes in the path names? What does your Apache error log say? Suppose you run IIS, then look into the Related links:

Comment: @mario: thanks, I didn't know errors would be logged in the apache logs. It says `'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` How can I make it use the same PATH as the normal shell?

Comment: You could explicitly add the required directories to the path at the beginning of your your batch script. You can check current path settings by exec-ing `cmd /c path` and checking the output.

Comment: I think you could try the SetEnv and PassEnv directive in an .htaccess or your httpd.conf file. Eventually Apache restricts it for some security reason. But anyway, also try to adapt your system PATH too. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out the problem; I installed ruby just for this and added it to my `PATH` environment variable, and it started working immediately for command prompts.

However it didn't work for PHP, so I decided to restart my computer. After that it worked.

Comment: That's a bit extreme. Environment variables are set for an application when it starts, and any changes you make later via the system properties won't automatically propagate to already-running apps). All you'd have had to do was restart the web server process.

Comment: I had this problem trying to get 'javac' to recognize. Worked immediately in Command prompt but not in PHP.

Comment: You saved me hours (after some hours)

Comment: AHHHHH! after much fruitless debugging, came across this simple solution... restarted wamp and it works just fine now. ha.

Comment: Indeed for me was also something with restarting Windows, the path was in user variables for current account but not in system variables.

Answer (score 0):

First chdir("C:\Ruby191\bin\"), then run lessc.bat.

Comment: I don't want to; I want to stay in my directory.